# Haskell - How to search if elements of one list exist in another

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to define a function in Haskell that will check if elements in list A are all in list B and return a Boolean.

So given the following:

```
listb = [a,b,c,d]

function :: [char]->Bool
```

the function should check that the input list only contains elements of listb
the input list also *cannot exceed a length of n*.

These are some of the methods I've tried but none of them seem to work:

```
function :: [char] -> Bool
function xs = length xs == n && isElem xs

isElem :: [char] -> Bool
isElem (x:xs) = x  `elem` listb && isElem xs
```

This failed for valid inputs.

Ive also tried:

```
function :: [char] -> Bool
function xs = length xs == n && whileValid xs

whileValid :: [char] -> Bool
whileValid (x:xs)
    |x `elem` listb = True && whileValid xs
    |otherwise = False
```

This fails for the same reason.

What is wrong about these methods and how do I define this function for it to work?

Comment: what is `n`? Can you provide valid inputs where your function failed? I think your problem is *underspecified* right now.

Comment: Sorry, n is the length that the input list needs to be to be valid. so if n = 4 then the length of the input list needs to equal four. Its just an extra constraint on the input list in addition to needing all its elements be in listb.

Comment: How does it fail?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're trying to check two unrelated things:

1. Are the elements of a list `xs` a subset of the elements of another list, `ys`?
2. Is the length of `xs` at most `n`?

The easy thing to do is check these separately.

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

isSubset :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isSubset xs ys = all (`S.member` yset) xs where
  yset = S.fromList ys

lengthAtMost :: Int -> [a] -> Bool
lengthAtMost n _ | n < 0 = False
lengthAtMost _ [] = True
lengthAtMost n (_ : xs) = lengthAtMost (n-1) xs
```

You can save some more time by weaving these operations together, but my phone is running out of batteries, so I'll leave that for later.

Answer (score 3):

Generalizing the concept to any type being an instance of `Eq` class, you may simply do as follows;

```
import Control.Applicative

exists :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
exists x y = any id $ (==) <$> x <*> y

*Main> exists [1,2,3] [3,4,5]
True
*Main> exists [1,2,3] [7,4,5]
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a few problems:

1. Types start with upper-case letters, where type variables start lower case, thus

   ```
   function :: [char] -> Bool
   ```

   is not what you want, but either `function :: [Char] -> Bool` which I would write `isSubSet :: String -> Bool` or more general `isSubSet :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool`.
2. Usually in haskell you do not use global constants like

   ```
   listB :: [Char]
   listB = ['a'..'d']
   ```
3. But rather parametrize functions - so

   ```
   isSubSetOf :: String -> String -> Bool
   isSubSetOf [] _ = True
   isSubSetOf small@(x:xs) big = (length small <= length big)
                              && (x `elem` big && isSubsetOf xs big)

   isSubSet x = isSubSetOf x listB
   ```

would be a correct implementation by type signature and it is a total function, which is a fancy way of saying - all cases of input types are handled, you missed the base case for lists, i.e. handling the empty list.

But it has a few (logical) errors which you need to solve:

- checking for `length` in every step is not necessary, in fact it is not necessary at all - and it is slowing down your algorithm!
- look at the test case like `isSubSetOf "aab" "abbb"`.

Comment: The constraint should either be `Ord a`, `(Eq a, Hashable a)`, or `Enum a`. Just `Eq a` admits only inefficient implementations.

Comment: @dfeuer indeed you are right - for any production grade, or better non learning grade version of this problem I would use existing data structures like `HashMap` or `Set`.

Comment: Even for "learning grade", most students understand `sort`. You can get tolerable performance with just that and some care.